# Can I encrypt Windows' SAM file?

Tags: encryption, passwords, bios

i recently learned that the SAM file in Windows is easily crackable, and even if an attacker couldn't find my password, there are tools that allow password removal, account elevation and even account creation. I know that this requires a live cd and physical access to the computer, but sometimes it happens to have to give your laptop to someone or something like that. Is there a way to secure the SAM file so that no one can access it or modify it?

I know i can ensure the disk's safety by setting a BIOS password, but are BIOS passwords really reliable?

And if you're kind enough, can you provide some articles about safety tips concerning physical access to a computer?

Answer (score 2):

Without physical security, nothing can be guaranteed. You can only make things harder.

BIOS passwords seem of some value though many can be reset by someone with physical access to your computer. Particularly if they can pop the case to access the internals. While you really can't prevent this short of replacing vulnerable hardware, you should be able to tell something's wrong because it won't ask for a password on the next boot.

Perhaps better than a BIOS password would be to enable full disk encryption via a tool such as [Bitlocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/bitlocker-drive-encryption-overview). When encrypted, even someone with physical access to your computer won't be able to modify the SAM as they can't read the disk. They can still erase the disk, but can't read it. It would be best if you shutdown your computer (as compared to sleep it) as full disk encryption is susceptible to [cold-boot attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack).

Comment: setup bitlocker with transparent encryption: problem solved.